# Azure B2C openid authentication for Tableau

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, tableau-cloud

Is it possible to integrate azure b2c custom flow with Tableau? According [docs](https://help.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/openid_auth_server_config.htm) I need to specify symmetric key (client secret) in tableau configuration. I am familiar with authorization code flow for public clients (interactive), but I know client secret is needed for client credentials grant flow, it's machine to machine interaction with no place for user in the middle. I am afraid to get next flow:

`Show form for user -> send to idp creds -> get token`

Instead I'd like to use custom policy, which redirects to external idp's, and finally I get token

`redirect user to b2c -> redirect to external idp -> prove identity -> redirect to tableau with token`